# How to exit OnPostAsync if record was not changed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

If someone opens the Edit screen for a row and does nothing but look, how can I get the OnPostAsync to exit instead of updating some fields and saving?

```
        //POST
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }
```

---

### I want to exit here if nothing changed

```
        Dances_Moderated.LastUpdated = DateTime.Today;
        Dances_Moderated.DanceStatus = "WaitingOK";
        Dances_Moderated.UserID = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserID"));


        _context.Attach(Dances_Moderated).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is just to check against the database record which you are trying to update. If none of the values have changed, then you can return from your action, before modifying lastUpdated, danceStatus, et. cetera

Comment: Too many values to check. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use js to check if someone changed the fields.Use a js varaible to store the default value,and before calling `OnPostAsync`,comparing the new data and the js variable.And add a route parameter `Edited` to pass data to OnPostAsync,if data is edited,`Edited` is true.Else,`Edited` is false.

Comment: I used the jquery on input and on change to enable a Submit button that was disabled on load.

Comment: Can you share your view code and js?

Answer (score 0):

I thought there was some sort of "state" in model or context that would have changed.

I used jquery to enable the Submit button(which loads disabled) if any inputs or pulldowns had changes.

```
    $('input[type=text].form-control').on("input", function () {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        $('#btnSave').attr('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('#btnSave').attr('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

For the pulldowns I found no way to include them easily in my check so I just used their id's and the code above. Pretty easy boilerplate copy and paste. Below are 2 of the examples to deal with pulldowns.

```
    $('#Dances_Moderated_Ages').on("change", function () {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        $('#btnSave').attr('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('#btnSave').attr('disabled', true);
    }
});

$('#Dances_Moderated_SingleDate').on("change", function () {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        $('#btnSave').attr('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('#btnSave').attr('disabled', true);
    }
});
```